# Mislabeled Boxes

Tags: probability

Suppose we have three boxes that are mislabeled: Blue, Red, Mixed. The mixed box contains both blue and red balls. What is the minimum number of balls that you can pick to determine the correct labeling of the boxes?

Box 1 can either be: Red or Mixed

Box 2 can be: Blue or Mixed

Box 3 can be: Blue or Red

So we can keep picking red balls in Box 1 and then only come to a blue ball later on. The same applies for Box 2. What is a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: Hint: If we interpret the question as meaning *all* the labels are wrong, one is enough.

Comment: Small note: this might be better placed at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Choose one ball from Box 3 and then see where the reasoning leads you depending on whether the ball is blue or red. This assumes you have one of each box: red, blue, and mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Box 3 can not be MIXED an can only be one color. Picking from it tells you its color, and from that all other boxes can be determined.

Example: You pick box 3 and pick a red ball, this means box 3 is RED

Box 1 cant be BLUE, and now cant be RED, so Box 1 is MIXED

Box 2 must then be BLUE, as no other options remain.

Answer (score 0):

First select a ball from box 3. Suppose it comes out to be Blue
Then box 3 has only blue
Then this implies box 2 is mixed.
Then the only box left. I.e box 1 has to be red.
So number of attempts is basically just 1